# Not sure why this code won't work, keeps on getting index error [Python]

Tags: python

#This is supposed to be a one input calculator but its not working. The index error keeps coming for no reason for num1 and num2. num1 and num2 get their values from the lists opsL and s2L. The code is suppose to work in one input for example (input = 5*20-10/5) and it goes in order from multiplication, division, addition and subtraction = 5*20-10/5 = 100-10/5 = 100-2 = 98

```
Input = input("Input: ")
while Input.isalpha():
    Input = input("Invalid, Input: ")

ops = Input
nums = Input
s = nums
Count = len(Input)
AnswerL = []
Waitops = []
Waitnums = []
for n in range(Count):
    s = s.replace("/", " ")
    s = s.replace("*", " ")
    s = s.replace("+", " ")
    s = s.replace("-", " ")
    s2 = [int(n) for n in s.split()]
    s2L = s2

for n in range(Count):
    ops = ops.replace("0", "")
    ops = ops.replace("1", "")
    ops = ops.replace("2", "")
    ops = ops.replace("3", "")
    ops = ops.replace("4", "")
    ops = ops.replace("5", "")
    ops = ops.replace("6", "")
    ops = ops.replace("7", "")
    ops = ops.replace("8", "")
    ops = ops.replace("9", "")
    ops = ''.join(i for i in ops if not i.isdigit())
    opsL = ops
#Don't mind the n, I was using it during the test
n = 1
while len(s) != 0 and len(ops) != 0:
    num1 = s2L[0]
    num2 = s2L[1]
    if opsL[0] == "*":
        Answer = num1 * num2
        AnswerL.append(Answer)
        s2L.pop(0)
        s2L.pop(0)
        opsL = opsL[1:]
        n = 0
    elif opsL[0] == "/" and len(s2L) > 1:
        Answer = num1 / num2
        AnswerL.append(Answer)
        s2L.pop(0)
        s2L.pop(0)
        opsL = opsL[1:]
        n = 0
    elif opsL[0] == "/" and len(s2L) < 1:
        Waitops = opsL[0]
        Waitnum = s2L[0]
        opsL = opsL[1:]
        s2L.pop(0)
    elif opsL[0] == "+":
        Answer = num1 + num2
        AnswerL.append(Answer)
        s2L.pop(0)
        s2L.pop(0)
        opsL = opsL[1:]
        n = 0
    elif opsL[0] == "+":
        Answer = num1 + num2
        AnswerL.append(Answer)
        s2L.pop(0)
        s2L.pop(0)
        opsL = opsL[1:]
        n = 0
    elif opsL[0] == "-" and len(opsL) == 0 and len(Waitops) == 0:
        Answer = num1 - num2
        AnswerL.append(Answer)
        s2L.pop(0)
        s2L.pop(0)
        opsL = opsL[1:]
        n = 0
    elif opsL[0] == "-" and len(opsL) != 0 or len(Waitops) != 0:
        Answer = num1 - num2
        AnswerL.append(Answer)
        s2L.pop(0)
        s2L.pop(0)
        opsL = opsL[1:]
        n = 0
    elif Waitops[0] == "/" and AnswerL != 0:
        num1 = AnswerL[0]
        AnswerL.pop(0)
        num2 = Waitnum[0]
        Waitnum = Waitnum[1:]
        Answer = num1 / num2
        AnswerL.append(Answer)
        n = 0
    elif Waitops[0] == "-" and AnswerL != 0:
        num1 = AnswerL[0]
        AnswerL.pop(0)
        num2 = Waitnum[0]
        Waitnum = Waitnum[1:]
        Answer = num1 / num2
        n = 0

print(Answer)
print(opsL)
print(s2L)
```

Comment: Please provide the full error message, starting from the word `Traceback`. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's this line that is causing the issue:

```
num1 = s2L[0]
num2 = s2L[1]
```

At some point, s2L becomes a list containing only one element and when you try s2L[1], it is trying to index the 2nd element, which, of course, doesn't exist.

You might want to change the line above where you check len != 0 to be more specific, say, len > 1 (or something like that).

Use "pdb" to step through your code. That way you can see how the list is changing at every step. https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/